# Exporting Gridview to Excel, and PDF not working.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

My Mockup of the Page with the Grid View:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; height: 447px;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" GridLines="Both" RowStyle-BorderWidth="0" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

My VB Code for export to Excel button option using itextSharp dll:

```
Protected Sub ExportAsExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportAsExcel.Click
        'Exporting the results to an excel spreadsheet
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        GridView1.AllowPaging = False
        GridView1.DataBind()

        'Change the Header Row back to white color
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")

        'Apply style to Individual Cells
        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Style.Add("background-color", "green")
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(i)

            'Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

            'Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")

            'Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                row.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
                row.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
                row.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
                row.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            End If
        Next
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw)

        'style to format numbers to string
        Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
        Response.Write(style)
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
End Sub
```

My code for exporting the page as a pdf using itextsharp dll is below:

```
Protected Sub ExportAsPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportAsPDF.Click

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        GridView1.AllowPaging = False
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A0, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

Not sure what is needed to do here i have the following imports as well.

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.html
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
Imports System.IO
```

However, the iTextSharp.text.html imported is not being used i dont know why. just a few days ago this code worked perfectly fine. and not it doesn't. i got this code from the following url::
Click [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx)!

Comment: You didn't say which version of iTextSharp you use. Please modify your code to work with `XMLWorker` instead of `HTMLWorker` (obsolete) and see if your issue still occurs when you use iTextSharp version `5.5.9`.

Comment: Where would I find that version!

Comment: Why, on the official website of course! http://itextpdf.com

Comment: Or on GitHub http://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases

Comment: I don't know who gave you a downvote, it wasn't me.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that I upvote questions when I find them on Google when I look for a solution to a problem of mine - I upvote the answers that helped me *and* the question. *Your question does not particularly address a problem that I have, so I do not see a compelling reason to upvote it.* I see that you are a rather new SO user with still much room to grow reputation-wise, but asking for upvotes is not the best way to increase reputation.

Comment: No problem @AmedeeVanGasse . This isn't for me. i am a java person just new to .net and really wanted help in this particular issue. But thank you once again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try following code. found from [www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Using sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    'To Export all pages
    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
    Me.BindGrid()

    GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White
    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
        cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        row.BackColor = Color.White
        For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
            If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
            Else
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor
            End If
            cell.CssClass = "textmode"
        Next
    Next

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    'style to format numbers to string
    Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
    Response.Write(style)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
End Using
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
' Verifies that the control is rendered
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

'http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200079/All-in-One-Export-Data-in-ASP-NET'

This helped the most in which i was able to use the code above to solve the issue that i was receiving. If anyone is facing this issue use the link above. it will help a lot.